# How can I create a dropdown that returns a functional component as item with MUI and React?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, material-ui

I have the following (dummy) components:

```js
const OwnerList = () => {
  return (
    <Box
      sx={{
        display: 'flex',
      }}
      className="owner-container"
    >
      <Avatar src='https://hips.hearstapps.com/hmg-prod.s3.amazonaws.com/images/actor-robert-pattinson-attends-the-opening-ceremony-of-the-news-photo-1588147075.jpg?crop=1.00xw:0.669xh;0,0.0920xh&resize=480:*' sx={{ width: 70, height: 70 }}>
      </Avatar>
      <Box
        className='testz'
      >
        <Typography sx={{ fontSize: 14 }}>
          Robert Douglas Thomas Pattinson
        </Typography>
      </Box>
      <Box className='owner-iconbutton-container'>
        <IconButton className='owner-iconbutton' size="large">
          <SwapVertIcon />
        </IconButton>
      </Box>
    </Box>
  )
}

export const OwnerListDropdown = () => {
  return (
    <Box sx={{ minWidth: 120 }}>
      <FormControl fullWidth>
        <InputLabel variant="standard" htmlFor="uncontrolled-native">
          User
        </InputLabel>
        <NativeSelect
          defaultValue={30}
          inputProps={{
            name: 'User',
            id: 'uncontrolled-native',
          }}
        >
          <option value={10}><OwnerList /></option>
          <option value={20}><OwnerList /></option>
          <option value={30}><OwnerList /></option>
        </NativeSelect>
      </FormControl>
    </Box>
  )
}
```

My intention is to generate a dropdown that contains multiple card items and allow the user to select the card (or at least have some item like Avatar - info). Sadly (and perhaps obviously) with my current approach i'm not achieving this goal. When the  is called, it just display the following:

[image: Wrong output with dropdown component]

Is there a way to make a personalized dropdown that works as intended?

Comment: `<option>` elements are not full fledged HTML Elements.  You probably won't be able to do this.

Comment: If you want to use MUI, I would look at Popper and Backdrop. Combine those two and you should be able to make something pretty decent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `@mui/material/Select` instead of `@mui/material/NativeSelect` like this:

```
import * as React from "react";
import Box from "@mui/material/Box";
import InputLabel from "@mui/material/InputLabel";
import FormControl from "@mui/material/FormControl";
import Select from "@mui/material/Select";
import { Typography } from "@mui/material";
import SwapVertIcon from "@mui/icons-material/SwapVert";
import Avatar from "@mui/material/Avatar";
import IconButton from "@mui/material/IconButton";
import MenuItem from "@mui/material/MenuItem";

const OwnerList = ({ value }) => {
  return (
    <Box
      sx={{
        display: "flex"
      }}
      className="owner-container"
    >
      <Avatar
        src="https://hips.hearstapps.com/hmg-prod.s3.amazonaws.com/images/actor-robert-pattinson-attends-the-opening-ceremony-of-the-news-photo-1588147075.jpg?crop=1.00xw:0.669xh;0,0.0920xh&resize=480:*"
        sx={{ width: 70, height: 70 }}
      ></Avatar>
      <Box className="testz">
        <Typography sx={{ fontSize: 14 }}>
          Robert Douglas Thomas Pattinson {value}
        </Typography>
      </Box>
      <Box className="owner-iconbutton-container">
        <IconButton className="owner-iconbutton" size="large">
          <SwapVertIcon />
        </IconButton>
      </Box>
    </Box>
  );
};

const OwnerListDropdown = () => {
  return (
    <Box sx={{ minWidth: 120 }}>
      <FormControl fullWidth>
        <InputLabel variant="standard" htmlFor="uncontrolled-native">
          User
        </InputLabel>
        <Select
          defaultValue={30}
          inputProps={{
            name: "User",
            id: "uncontrolled-native"
          }}
        >
          <MenuItem value={10}>
            <OwnerList value={10} />
          </MenuItem>
          <MenuItem value={20}>
            <OwnerList value={20} />
          </MenuItem>
          <MenuItem value={30}>
            <OwnerList value={30} />
          </MenuItem>
        </Select>
      </FormControl>
    </Box>
  );
};

export default OwnerListDropdown;
```

You can take a look at [this sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/mui-select-b6clrq?file=/demo.tsx) for a live working example of this solution.

Comment: Thank you! This worked pretty well, appreciated the sandbox detail!

Comment: You are welcome and best wishes.